# grails mail connection refused

Tags: email, grails, jakarta-mail

it seems i have tried the [mail](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail) config in the way that its docs said, but still i get:

```
Error 500: Executing action [x] of controller [x] caused exception: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP
```

I am using google apps for my email - me@dogself.com is using gmail. i cannot get grails to send out a test message on my dev box (win 7).

my config is:

```
   host = "smtp.gmail.com"
   port = 465
   username = "autoresponse@dogself.com"
   password = "x"
   props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
            "mail.smtp.debug":"true",
            "mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
```

**edit:**
do i need to have some sort of a signed key to support **ssl connection** to gmail?

Comment: Have you checked Windows Firewall? Maybe it's the culprit.

Comment: just turned off the firewall - no difference in the outcome still connection refused :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
props = ["mail.transport.protocol":"smtps",
         "mail.smtps.host":"smtp.gmail.com",
         "mail.smtps.port":"465",
         "mail.smtps.auth":"true"]
```

That seems to be [the standard set of params necessary to connect to Google's SMTP server](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0570.html).  The key thing is to use `smtps` instead of `smtp` plus `TLS`.

Comment: this does seem to work, though my app hangs for unrelated reason (i think).

Comment: Just for information, add these mail configuration as "grails { mail { .... } } " in config.groovy. I also encountered same issue. It is resolved by adding mail configuration into "grails {}".

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using the [Grails Mail Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail) and give it another try.  There is a sample configuration for Gmail near the end of that web page.

Comment: that is what i am using.. i should have specified :P

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove:

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable: "true"
```

I've gotten mine to work without that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting properties in your "props" declaration:

`"mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true"` is used for a plaintext handshake with the server, and then starts TLS encryption negotiations with the server.

`"mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"` requires an encrypted handshake.

The port you specified (465) could work with either, but is normally for encrypted use. If the server supports it, I would suggest using the first property `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true"` and augment it with `"mail.smtp.starttls.required":"true"` to ensure that your messages are encrypted between your application and the SMTP server, and remove the  `"mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"`